# Facebook sharing: wrong sharing data when og:url used

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to share some article at Facebook (without creating fb social app).

The header of file what I feed to https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php is following:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<!meta property="og:url" content="url to some website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:image" content="url to image" />
<meta property="og:description" content="some description" />
```

The problem is - each time when i try to set og:url, title, image and description catches up from "url to some website" and suppress values that I typed explicitly here! Also og:type property changes from "article" to "website".

How can I fix this problem? Does I need to create fb social app for this?

Answer (score 1):

I don"t know exactly what you want, but og:url basically ignores any other parameters you gave to the header.

You'd better check this :)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button